# Hmlt5 audio not working with java http server

Tags: java, html, audio, client-server

I'm creating one java http server, that usues html5 to play music.

The problem is that when I connect to the server over my browser ( chromium, firefox) it does not play the audio. But if I select to my browser show me the font code and I copy the font code and paste it on a file .html and I open this file with browser its works. What is my problem?

This is my java server

```
package br.ufla.sd.trabfinal;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerHttp extends Thread {

private Socket clientSocket;
private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static int portNumber = 8088;
private PrintWriter out;

/**
 * WebServer constructor.
 */

private ServerHttp(Socket clientSoc) {
    clientSocket = clientSoc;

    start();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    serverSocket = null;

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        System.out.println("Connection Socket Created");
        try {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Waiting for Connection");
                new ServerHttp(serverSocket.accept());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port:" + portNumber);
        System.exit(1);
    } finally {
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not close port: " + portNumber);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}

public void run() {

    System.out.println("New Communication, Thread " + this.getId()
            + " Started");

    try {
        // remote is now the connected socket
        System.out.println("Connection, sending data.");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        // read the data sent. We basically ignore it,
        // stop reading once a blank line is hit. This
        // blank line signals the end of the client HTTP
        // headers.
        String str = ".";
        while (!str.equals(""))
            str = in.readLine();

        // Send the response
        // Send the headers
        out.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        //out.println("Content-Type: text/html");

        //out.println("Server: Bot");
        // this blank line signals the end of the headers

        out.println("");

        // Send the HTML page
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">");
        out.println("<title> Músicas</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<H1>Welcome</H1>");
        out.println("<audio controls>");
        out.println("<source src=\"/****/Horse.wav\" type=\"audio/wav\">");
        out.println("Your browser does not support the audio element.");
        out.println("</audio>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }

}
```

}

And another thing, if I change the file location to a online sound like this site : [Site sound](http://www.doghause.com/sounds/Horse.wav) it works... Is someone know what is my problem?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are just giving a path to the audio source. Think what will happen once this page loads on a browser and the user clicks to start the audio file.

Your browser will send a request again to the server to fetch the audio file. At this point in time, your server should accept the request and send the audio file back to the browser as an output stream.

The external link works because the file is present at the external link.

For your browser, the file is not present as your server doesn't seem to return any file for the request that the browser is making.

To confirm this you can check your browser's console. You will get a 404 for the audio file.

Comment: Thanks sanket, now I understand what is my problem... but how can I get information from the output stream using my browser?